# How can I perform a vulnerability scan in an angular/node application

Tags: node.js, angular, maven, jenkins-pipeline, owasp

I'm trying to setup a process to check the known vulnerabilities in an Angular 7 / Node project. How can I run a process like this? Are there any tools to use?

I already tried to run, using maven, the dependency-check-maven plugin but it creates me a report saying 0 things were checked.

Last execution results:

```
dependency-check version: 4.0.2
Report Generated On: Mar 27, 2019 at 17:02:49 +00:00
Dependencies Scanned: 0 (0 unique)
Vulnerable Dependencies: 0
Vulnerabilities Found: 0
Vulnerabilities Suppressed: 0
```

Those 0 in the Dependencies Scanned make me think "This is not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the owasp plug-in for jenkins that is running perfectly. I don't know if it's the best option, but for now it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try npm audit. It checks your node modules for known vulnerabilities:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit

Comment: I didn't find a way for the audit to generate a report and fail my build. Jenkins is giving me that.